# What's the best way to wrap a monix Task with a start time and end time print the difference?

Tags: scala, monix

This is what I'm trying right now but it only prints "hey" and not metrics.
I don't want to add metric related stuff in the main function.

```
import java.util.Date

import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

class A {
  def fellow(): Task[Unit] = {
    val result = Task {
      println("hey")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
    result
  }
}

trait AA extends A {
  override def fellow(): Task[Unit] = {
    println("AA")
    val result = super.fellow()
    val start = new Date()
    result.foreach(e => {
      println("AA", new Date().getTime - start.getTime)
    })
    result
  }
}

val a = new A with AA
val res: Task[Unit] = a.fellow()
Await.result(res.runAsync, Duration.Inf)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can describe a function such as this:

```
def measure[A](task: Task[A], logMillis: Long => Task[Unit]): Task[A] =
  Task.deferAction { sc =>
    val start = sc.clockMonotonic(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    val stopTimer = Task.suspend {
      val end = sc.clockMonotonic(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      logMillis(end - start)
    }

    task.redeemWith(
      a => stopTimer.map(_ => a)
      e => stopTimer.flatMap(_ => Task.raiseError(e))
    )
  }
```

Some piece of advice:

1. `Task` values should be pure, along with the functions returning `Task`s — functions that trigger side effects and return `Task` as results are broken

   - `Task` is not a 1:1 replacement for `Future`; when describing a `Task`, all side effects should be suspended (wrapped) in `Task`
   - `foreach` triggers the `Task`'s evaluation and that's not good, because it triggers the side effects; I was thinking of deprecating and removing it, since its presence is tempting
2. stop using trait inheritance and just use plain functions — unless you deeply understand OOP and subtyping, it's best to avoid it if possible; and if you're into the Cake pattern, stop doing it and maybe join a support group
3. never measure time duration via `new Date()`, you need a monotonic clock for that and on top of the JVM that's `System.nanoTime`, which can be accessed via Monix's `Scheduler` by `clockMonotonic`, as exemplified above, the `Scheduler` being given to you via `deferAction`
4. stop blocking threads, because that's error prone — instead of doing `Thread.sleep`, do `Task.sleep` and all `Await.result` calls are problematic, unless they are in `main` or in some other place where dealing with asynchrony is not possible

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Comment: for the record : a and e lanbda have to be inverted and separated by a lambda

Comment: In the latest version of Task, there is now a Task.timed function.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Pierre mentioned, latest version of Monix Task has `Task.timed`, you can do

```scala
timed <- task.timed
(duration, t) = timed
```